# Millions of device information fetching from cassandra using GOLANG Driver

Tags: cassandra, scylla

I am using Cassandra database to fetch millions of devices data based on device_id as partition key with parallel from API using GO-LANG DRIVER.
some one please guide me which driver parameters need to set which value on GO-LANG Driver ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking into this code example in golang (using gocql driver), that demonstrates how to fetch millions of rows in parallel from Scylla?
It's basically a full table scan (or a large range scan) that shows Scylla's ability for great parallelism.

Read more in this post:

- https://www.scylladb.com/2017/03/28/parallel-efficient-full-table-scan-scylla/

The actual code example:

- https://github.com/scylladb/scylla-code-samples/tree/master/efficient_full_table_scan_example_code

Comment: i am using cassandra database 3.11.4  and not using scylla .

Comment: Maybe you should try Scylla. :)
The client code is the same - Cassandra and Scylla share the same CQL-based drivers. But the performance will be much better on Scylla.

Comment: @sateesh, Scylla is a drop-in replacement for Cassandra, so I would definitely look into it. Much easier to use and maintain, the migration is pretty easy (no code change or data modeling change needed).
And there's Scylla Cloud which is a managed service...

Comment: i am facing issue with poor read performance on Scylla compare to Cassandra using normal HDD. because my company never using SSD disks. Can some one confirm, is it possible to achieve better read performance than Cassandra using normal HDD or not ? If YES. what changes required scylla configuration and what are the files need to configure ? Please help me

Comment: Sateesh, I believe that I and few others provided you with few reasons as to why you could be hitting that issue.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59677972/what-is-the-difference-between-scylla-read-path-and-cassandra-read-path/59687819#59687819