# Cassandra/Scylla cartesian product in a simple WHERE IN query?

Tags: cassandra, scylla

I have a simple table like `group(id varcahr(64) primary key, size bigint)` and I need to find if a set of ids are in the table. I use a simple query:

```
SELECT id FROM group WHERE id IN (<id1>..<idn>);
```

idn can be pretty big and when I run the query, I get the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLTransientException: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.ServerError: clustering-key cartesian product size 107 is greater than maximum 100
```

Differently from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59936536/scylladb-clustering-key-cartesian-product-size-600-is-greater-than-maximum-100) I'd like to understand why
a cartesian product is needed when a search in the index would be enough and would not require the product which I agree can get to an unmanageable size.

Comment: Got it.  Question reopened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message (which I assume you got from ScyllaDB?) is misleading:

Both Scylla and Cassandra want to limit on the number of different row queries that one query may turn to; For example, imagine that you have `WHERE a in (1,2,3,4,5) AND b in (1,2,3,4,5)` this can result in 5x5, i.e., 25 separate row requests. This sort of "cartesian product" can quickly get huge even with a short-looking query, which is why it is limited by two configuration options, `max_partition_key_restrictions_per_query` and `max_clustering_key_restrictions_per_query`. Both of these options default in ScyllaDB to **100**.

Although exceeding this limit can happen easily with a Cartesian product of several "IN", as you saw it can also happen if you have just one "IN" with just a very long list that has more than the configured limit (100). In that case, the error message is indeed misleading.

Although the fact that `max_clustering_key_restrictions_per_query` defaults to 100 has dubious merit (see https://github.com/scylladb/scylladb/issues/10577), in your case you are querying 107 different **partitions** so it is the configuration option `max_partition_key_restrictions_per_query` is the one causing your problem and also set by default to 100. In your use case, you can safely increase this configuration option, and allow bigger IN lists.

Just don't overdo `max_partition_key_restrictions_per_query` - the code to read a huge number of random partitions is inefficient, and there is usually a bettter way to do this. The most efficient way is to store related rows in *one* partition, and then read the entire partition - instead of indexing 1,000 different rows by key. This may, of course, require you to change your data model and I don't know if or how it fits your use case.

Comment: I opened a ScyllaDB issue https://github.com/scylladb/scylladb/issues/15627 about the misleading error message. The error you reported is misleading in two ways: It says " clustering-key cartesian product size", which the query does not involve clustering keys (it lists partition keys) and doesn't involve a cartesian product of INs - but just one.

Comment: (many thanks for the explanation, first of all)

mmhh... I am not sure, though, it fully explains the case: I missed some information, but I've got that message even reducing the IN list to 25 elements, definitely not going over 100; and with a db with less than 10K rows; maybe even with such a small db I may have more than 100 partitions? still the query should not touch more than 25 partitions... 
Also, if only keys are involved, I am still not sure any cartesian product is needed: despite the number of elements in the logic expression, all should turn into union/intersect of sets of key

Comment: A single IN with just 25 elements should NOT result in this message. Can you paste an exact request you used? In any case, as I noted the error message is misleading - it counts the individual rows that the INs need to fetch, and may trigger even with a single IN.

Comment: I have tried to reproduce it, but could not any more. I was most likely doing something wrong. I also see the cartesian product if the WHERE condition contains more than one IN; maybe you could suggest also a simple optimization in the case there is only one condition?

Comment: As I tried to explain, a cartesian product (multiple INs) just makes it easier to cross the "100" threshold (e.g., three INs with just 5 options in each will result in `5*5*5 > 100`), but you can cross the same threshold with just one IN with more than 100 options (in the example error message you quoted, you had 107 options in a single IN). If you do need more than 100, just increase the `max_partition_key_restrictions_per_query` configuration option, as I suggested above. If you see yourself needing 10,000 - then you should reconsider your data model (try using clustering keys).